# trying to pass value from a textbox into a variable in python with flask

Tags: python, html, flask, input, backend

I have a simple frontend with a textbox and upon a click, I want whatever is in that textbox to be passed into a variable. How would I go about doing this.

Heres a little bit of my app.py file:

```
input = input('Type headline here')
#MAKING PREDICTIONS BASED ON NEW DATA
predict = model2.predict(input)
print(predict)

#MAKING THE FRONTEND

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)


@app.route('/')
def predict():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods = ["POST"])
def predict2():
    text = request.form["input"]
    #return render_template('index.html', prediction = predict)
    return text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

heres my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FAKE NEWS DETECTOR</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Enter the news headline to see if its fake or real</h1>

<form method="POST">
        <input name = 'input'>
        <input type = "submit">


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the user input to be stored into the input variable with another output returned. With the setup I have right now I just get a "method not allowed, method is not allowed for requested url" message. How would I go about solving this?

Comment: You have two routes for the same URL. That won't work. Also, you're allowing the `"POST "` method and not `"POST"`; the two are *not* the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only have one route per URL, and perform a check on the `request` object to determine how to proceed

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # get the form data
        text = request.form['input']
        # do your prediction here
        render_template('index.html', text=text)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: When I use this code, I just get an internal server error

Comment: If you're running your code with `debug=True` it should tell you more information, does it say anything else in the terminal output? It should be noted this should be the *only route*, and that you should *remove both the other routes you had posted in your question and replace with only this one*